# Unable to run jmeter 3.0 script with JSON path POST-processor with jmeter-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

If I run the script as

```
./jmeter.sh -n -t test_load.jmx from apache-jmeter-3.0/bin
```

it works fine, whereas when I run the same script from Maven, I get this error:

```
[debug] ------------------------------- : JSONPostProcessor : JSONPostProcessor
[debug] ---- Debugging information ----
[debug] message             : JSONPostProcessor
[debug] cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
[debug] cause-message       : JSONPostProcessor
[debug] class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
[debug] required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
[debug] converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
[debug] path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[7]/hashTree/hashTree[2]/JSONPostProcessor
[debug] line number         : 160
```

This is line number 160:

```
    <JSONPostProcessor guiclass="JSONPostProcessorGui" testclass="JSONPostProcessor" testname="JSON Path PostProcessor-UserId" enabled="true">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.rajulonline.com</groupId>
   <artifactId>jmeter-demo</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>jmeter-demo</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.1</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                  <phase>verify</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>jmeter</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Added pom.xml, screenshot of the lib folder and lib/ext folder. Manually added the apache jmeter 3.0 core jar, along with it the json jars and the jmeter extra libs jar as well

Also attaching the screenshot of my lib & lib/ext folder
[image: Screenshot_lib/ext]

Jmeter project with version apache jmeter 2.13[image: Json Postprocessor error on apache 2.13 with extra libs added in the /lib/ext]

[image: /lib/ext folder]

Comment: Are you following these steps https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/automating-jmeter-tests-maven-jenkins/

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana I get this error only when the Json post processor is used in the sample request. Json Post processor is part of apache 3.0 jmeter. Not sure why it wont work on maven 4.0.

Comment: Can you show your Maven configuration ? pom.xml ?

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK Added the pom.xml for your reference.

Answer (score 2):

You're most probably using a 2.13 version of JMeter instead of a 3.0 through the dependencies management used by jmeter-maven-plugin.

You're also using a 3rd party plugin that you need to add to maven pom.xml.

Note that jmeter-maven-plugin-1.10.1 does not support JMeter 3.0.

The support for JMeter 3.0 has been officially released in version 2.X as per:

- https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

So you should upgrade to last version of jmeter-maven-plugin and follow this [documentation](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath#adding-jars-to-the-libext-directory) using as dependency:

> kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-json:2.6

But sinc JMeter 3.0, JSON extraction is supported OOTB by JMeter core so you wouldn't need any plugin.

Comment: Thank you Ubik load pack. When i run mvn -X verify, i believe jmeter 2.13 is being used for running the test.
[DEBUG] Copying artifacts, showing dependency trail: 
[DEBUG] com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.10.1
[DEBUG]  org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter:jar:2.13

And i see this exception message as well,
[debug] converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
[debug] path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[2]/JSONPostProcessor
[debug] line number         : 62
[debug] version             : 2.13 r1665067

Comment: You should be able to try the 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT if you use the snapshot repository ```<repository>
                    <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
                    <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>```  If it doesn't work it would be good to know about it.

Comment: @Ardesco I am not using the snapshot repository at the moment. I added the apache 3.0 jmeter core jar , along with it the json jars and the jmeter extra libs in the lib/ext as well. But i am getting Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.NullPointerException. I am not sure what is the jar im missing in the /lib/ext.

Comment: @rajul, what you are trying to do will not work. Your installation is broken as you're mixing at least 2 versions of JMeter in lib/ext.

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK With the current pom.xml mvn -X verify always installs apache jmeter core 2.13. Added couple of more screenshots. Even after adding the jmeter plugins in the lib/ext folder i still get the JSONPostProcessor error.

Is it possible to force jmeter-maven-plugin to install apache jmeter 3.0 because the script works fine on apache 3.0. Just not on 2.13.

Comment: @Ardesco i cloned git@github.com:jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin.git into my local, modified the /Users/lraghavan/jmeter-maven-plugin/src/it/basic-run/pom.xml to run the jmeter script with the Json post path processor. It works fine.  
The tests run when i hardcode the script names as
<jMeterTestFile>latest_test.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
<jMeterTestFile>oldest_test.jmx</jMeterTestFile>

But i am unable to parameterize the jmeter script as <jMeterTestFile>${filename}.jmx</jMeterTestFile>.

so mvn verify -Dfilename=latest_test does not execute the script.

Comment: You don't need to clone anything, or do anything fancy to use the snapshot version.  You simply need to add the snapshot repository to your POM and then use the 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT version of the plugin instead of the 1.10.1 version.

Comment: It is worth noting that as it is a snapshot version your milage may vary.  However you will not get JMeter 3.x running with the 1.x version of the JMeter Maven Plugin.